# Quadratic refinements of a bilinear form on finite abelian groups

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, finite-groups, quadratic-forms, abelian-groups, short-exact-sequences

$\DeclareMathOperator\Hom{Hom}$Let $A$ be a finite abelian group and $\text{Sym}(A)$ the (abelian) group of symmetric bilinear forms over $A$ valued in $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$.

A quadratic function on $A$ is $q:A\rightarrow \mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$ such that $q(-a)=q(a)$ and
$$
\chi_q(a,b)=q(a+b)-q(a)-q(b)
$$
is bilinear. Hence if $q$ is quadratic $\chi_q\in \text{Sym}(A)$. The map $q\rightarrow \chi_q$ is clearly linear and thus defines a homomorphism from the group $Q(A)$ of quadratic functions to $\text{Sym}(A)$.

1. Is this map surjective? In other words, is there always a quadratic refinement of a symmetric bilinear form valued in $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$? I think the answer is yes but I am not sure about a concrete proof.
2. Assuming the answer to the first question is yes, what is the kernel of the map? I think it should be isomorphic to $\Hom(A,\mathbb{Z}_2)$ by looking at examples (and from other abstract arguments, see [Is there a clear pattern for the degree $2n$ cohomology group of the $n$'th Eilenberg-MacLane space?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/450594/is-there-a-clear-pattern-for-the-degree-2n-cohomology-group-of-the-nth-eile)), but It is not clear to me how to prove this, and even how to see $\Hom(A,\mathbb{Z}_2)$ as a subgroup of $Q(A)$.

Comment: Question 2 is trivial: it is the set of all functions $q :A \to \mathbb R / \mathbb Z$ such that $q(-a) = q(a)$ and $q(a+b) = q(a) + q(b)$ identically, which is obviously $\mathrm{Hom}(A, \frac12 \mathbb Z / \mathbb Z)$.

Comment: Incidentally I was expecting to see the requirement $q(na) = n^2 q(a)$ for all $n \in \mathbb Z$, but I see this actually follows from $q(-a) = q(a)$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. By the classification of finite abelian groups we have $A \cong C_1 \oplus \cdots \oplus C_k$ for some cyclic groups $C_i = \langle g_i \rangle$ of prime power order $r_i$. Let $\chi: A \times A \to \mathbb R / \mathbb Z$ be a symmetric bilinear map. Observe that $\chi(g_i, g_j)$ has order dividing $\gcd(r_i, r_j)$ for all $i,j$. For each $i = 1, \dots, k$, let $q_i$ be a solution to $2q_i = \chi(g_i, g_i)$ such that $q_i$ has odd order if $r_i$ is odd (there is a unique choice if $r_i$ is odd and two choices if $r_i$ is even). Now define $q : A \to \mathbb R / \mathbb Z$ by
   $$q\left(\sum_{i=1}^k n_i g_i\right) = \sum_{i=1}^k n_i^2 q_i + \sum_{1 \le i < j \le k} \chi(g_i, g_j) n_i n_j.$$
   This is well-defined by our careful choice of $q_i$ and it is easy to check that $\chi_q = \chi$.
2. As mentioned in the comments, the kernel consists of the homomorphisms $q : A \to \mathbb R / \mathbb Z$ taking half-integer values, which can obviously be identified with $\mathrm{Hom}(A, \mathbb Z / 2 \mathbb Z)$.

Comment: Why do we need $q_i$ to have odd order when $r_i$ is odd?

Comment: @AndreaAntinucci For $q$ to be well-defined the expression on the right must depend only on $n_i$ modulo $r_i$. If you replace $n_i$ with $n_i + r_i$ the difference is $2n_i r_i q_i + r_i^2 q_i + \sum_{j \ne i} \chi(g_i, g_j) r_i n_j = r_i^2 q_i$, and this must be zero.

Comment: I am not sure I understand. If $r_i$ is odd $2$ is invertible in $C_i$ and any $q_i$ such that $2q_i=\chi(g_i,g_i)$ satisfies $q_i=2^{-1}\chi(g_i,g_i)$. But then since the order of $\chi(g_i,g_i)$ divides $r_i$ I get $r_iq_i=2^{-1}r_i\chi(g_i,g_i)=0$. Here it seems to me I am not assuming $q_i$ to have odd order. Actually on a cyclic group of odd order I think there is no concept of even or odd.

Comment: $q_i$ is an element of $\mathbb R/\mathbb Z$, not $C_i$. In $\mathbb R/\mathbb Z$ there are always exactly two solutions to $2x=y$. If $y$ has finite odd order $k$ then one of the solutions has order $k$ and the other has order $2k$.